# Using pip within a python script

Tags: python, svn, pip

I am writing a utility in python that needs to check for (and if necessary, install and even upgrade) various other modules with in a target project/virtualenv, based on user supplied flags and/or input.  I am currently trying to utilize 'pip' directly/programatically (because of it's existing support for the various repo types I will need to access), but I am having difficulty in finding examples or documentation on using it this way.

This seemed like the direction to go:

```
import pip
vcs = pip.vcs.VersionControl(url="http://path/to/repo/")
```

...but it gives no joy.

I need help with some of the basics aparently - like how can I use pip to pull/export a copy of an svn repo into a given local directory.  Ultimately, I will also need to use it for git and mercurial checkouts as well as standard pypi installs. Any links, docs or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "gives no joy"? Does it give an error message? Does it just not install?

Comment: It does not install or even return a value.  I then tried using the 'obtain' method on the vcs object to no avail either - in fact that did error out.  I just need some kind of example or documentation on it or even just a "best practices" for this sort of usage.

Comment: **bump**  ...anyone?  Even a terse 'Try reading "X"!', as long as X is accessible and sheds any light at all on this, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip uses a particular format for vcs urls. The format is

```
vcsname+url@rev
```

@rev is optional, you can use it to reference a specific commit/tag

To use pip to retrieve a repository from a generic vcs to a local directory you may do this

```
from pip.vcs import VcsSupport

req_url = 'git+git://url/repo'
dest_path = '/this/is/the/destination'

vcs = VcsSupport()
vc_type, url = req_url.split('+',1)
backend = vcs.get_backend(vc_type)
if backend:
    vcs_backend = backend(req_url)
    vcs_backend.obtain(dest_path)
else:
    print('Not a repository')
```

Check https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#id8 to know which vcs are supported

Comment: The link above is broken (an endless redirect loop), but it's not exactly what I was looking for anyway. Where are the docs for the pip module? I find all sorts of docs for the pip command line tool, but nothing for the pip module itself.

Comment: I've updated the link. I don't think I've ever read real documentation for the pip module, I think I checked the source code (sorry, too much time has passed).

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing the same since there really isn't much in the way of docs outside the command line. Thanks for the reply.